# jQuery edited Bootstrap datetimepicker not showing up

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I am trying to play around with Bootstrap datetimepicker but the jQuery code that I am using doesn't seem to work at all. I was breaking down someone else's working code from CodePen (using their jQuery code) but it does not work on mine and I've checked the classes, ids and libraries multiples times. Clueless here.

I was wondering if other clearer eyes would spot the problem.

Here's my **CodePen**: https://codepen.io/fergos2/pen/xxxeXqa

Here's the one I am basing mine on: https://codepen.io/johnfinkdesign/pen/NRyBZb

Thanks in advance for your help!

```js
if (/Mobi/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  // if mobile device, use native pickers
  $(".date-container input").attr("type", "date");
  $(".time-container input").attr("type", "time");
} else {
  // if desktop device, use DateTimePicker
  $("#datepicker").datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false,
    format: "DD-MM-YYYY",
    
    // disabling past dates
    minDate: moment(), 
    
    showTodayButton: true,
    icons: {
      next: "fa fa-chevron-right",
      previous: "fa fa-chevron-left",
      today: 'todayText',
    }
  });
  $("#timepicker").datetimepicker({
    format: "LT",
    icons: {
      up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
      down: "fa fa-chevron-down"
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  input {
    width: 20vw;
    padding: 10px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
  }
}

.date-container {
  position: relative;
  
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.time-container {
  position: relative;
}

.date-icon,
.time-icon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;

  cursor: pointer;
  color: #495057;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  padding: .64rem .75rem;
  border-top-right-radius: .25rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: .25rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


.todayText:before {
  content: "Today's Date"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="date-container" id="datepicker">
      <input placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
      <span class="date-icon">
         <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
       </span>
    </div>

    <div class="time-container" id="timepicker">
      <input placeholder="HH:MM">
      <span class="time-icon">
         <i class="fa fa-clock"></i>
       </span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Running the example gives an obvious error on `moment()`. Are you missing the `moment.js` library, or some other, perhaps?

Comment: @PaulT. the library is there... I am using https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js as the one used in the CodePen I am basing mine on...